# Android spooler crashes with SIGSEV while printing pdf with a page range

Tags: android, pdf, android-print-framework, android-pdf-api

When I try to print a 16-page PDF document with only certain pages selected (i.e. page range) the spooler crashes due to a SIGSEV (please see the dump below).  The same crash also happens when I try to 'print' to PDF.  Printing all pages of the document works fine.

Is this a bug in android print framework?

The dump when trying to print only the first page out of 16:

```
05-16 11:51:16.828 6058-6069/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfRenderer: closeDocument()
05-16 11:51:16.838 11898-11898/? I/MutexFileProvider: Released file: /data/user/0/com.android.printspooler/files/print_job_1fc0a791-435d-493c-8cff-7ff65c3a642e.pdf from thread: Thread[main,5,main]
05-16 11:51:16.838 11898-12249/? I/MutexFileProvider: Acquired file: /data/user/0/com.android.printspooler/files/print_job_1fc0a791-435d-493c-8cff-7ff65c3a642e.pdf by thread: Thread[AsyncTask #6,5,main]
05-16 11:51:16.838 6058-6068/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfEditor: openDocument()
05-16 11:51:16.838 6058-6494/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfEditor: removePages()
05-16 11:51:16.838 6058-6494/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfEditor: trying to remove page 15/16
05-16 11:51:16.838 6058-6494/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfEditor: trying to remove page 14/15
05-16 11:51:16.838 6058-6494/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfEditor: trying to remove page 13/14
05-16 11:51:16.838 6058-6494/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfEditor: trying to remove page 12/13
05-16 11:51:16.838 6058-6494/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfEditor: trying to remove page 11/12
05-16 11:51:16.838 6058-6494/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfEditor: trying to remove page 10/11
05-16 11:51:16.838 6058-6494/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfEditor: trying to remove page 9/10
05-16 11:51:16.848 6058-6494/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfEditor: trying to remove page 8/9
05-16 11:51:16.848 6058-6494/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfEditor: trying to remove page 7/8
05-16 11:51:16.848 6058-6494/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfEditor: trying to remove page 6/7
05-16 11:51:16.848 6058-6494/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfEditor: trying to remove page 5/6
05-16 11:51:16.848 6058-6494/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfEditor: trying to remove page 4/5
05-16 11:51:16.848 6058-6494/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfEditor: trying to remove page 3/4
05-16 11:51:16.848 6058-6494/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfEditor: trying to remove page 2/3
05-16 11:51:16.848 6058-6494/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfEditor: trying to remove page 1/2
05-16 11:51:16.848 6058-6495/? I/PdfManipulationService -> PdfEditor: write()
05-16 11:51:17.018 6058-6495/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 6495 (Binder_4)
05-16 11:51:17.088 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-16 11:51:17.088 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/heroltebmc/heroltebmc:6.0.1/MMB29K/G930W8VLU2APK3:user/release-keys'
05-16 11:51:17.088 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '8'
05-16 11:51:17.088 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
05-16 11:51:17.088 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG: pid: 6058, tid: 6495, name: Binder_4  >>> com.android.printspooler:renderer <<<
05-16 11:51:17.088 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8
05-16 11:51:17.098 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000007f7d61e700  x2   0000000000000621  x3   0000000000000000
05-16 11:51:17.098 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000007f5b03f2c8  x6   0000007f5b03f2bc  x7   ffffffffffffffff
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000000  x9   0000007f81195000  x10  0000007f81195610  x11  0000000000000018
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000000000000000  x13  ffffffffff000000  x14  0000000000000000  x15  0000000000000000
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000007f8134deb0  x17  0000007f80fb3174  x18  00000000ffffffff  x19  0000000000000000
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000000000000000  x21  0000007f5b03f2bc  x22  0000000000000621  x23  0000007f5b03f2c8
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000007f7d61e700  x25  0000000000000000  x26  0000000000000000  x27  0000000000000000
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     x28  0000000000000000  x29  0000007f5b03f170  x30  0000007f80fe50b4
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007f5b03f150  pc   0000007f80fb3174  pstate 0000000060000000
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000000000b9174  /system/lib64/libpdfium.so (_ZN14CPDF_ModuleMgr14GetFlateModuleEv)
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00000000000eb0b0  /system/lib64/libpdfium.so (_Z24FPDFAPI_FlateOrLZWDecodeiPKhjP15CPDF_DictionaryjRPhRj+364)
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00000000000eb440  /system/lib64/libpdfium.so (_Z14PDF_DataDecodePKhjPK15CPDF_DictionaryRPhRjR14CFX_ByteStringRPS1_ji+844)
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00000000000f3980  /system/lib64/libpdfium.so (_ZN14CPDF_StreamAcc11LoadAllDataEPK11CPDF_Streamiji+436)
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00000000000f621c  /system/lib64/libpdfium.so (_ZN11CPDF_Parser15GetObjectStreamEj+156)
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00000000000f7a20  /system/lib64/libpdfium.so (_ZN11CPDF_Parser17GetIndirectBinaryEjRPhRj+244)
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 00000000000be7ec  /system/lib64/libpdfium.so (_ZN12CPDF_Creator22WriteOldIndirectObjectEj+500)
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 00000000000beb04  /system/lib64/libpdfium.so (_ZN12CPDF_Creator12WriteOldObjsEP9IFX_Pause+84)
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00000000000c015c  /system/lib64/libpdfium.so (_ZN12CPDF_Creator15WriteDoc_Stage2EP9IFX_Pause+136)
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00000000000c1f90  /system/lib64/libpdfium.so (_ZN12CPDF_Creator8ContinueEP9IFX_Pause+172)
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00000000000c2598  /system/lib64/libpdfium.so (_ZN12CPDF_Creator6CreateEj+288)
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 000000000008dfd0  /system/lib64/libpdfium.so (_Z14_FPDF_Doc_SavePvP15FPDF_FILEWRITE_mii+120)
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 000000000010891c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so
05-16 11:51:17.108 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 0000000003314208  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 0x2f5b000)
05-16 11:51:17.288 3144-3144/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_06
05-16 11:51:17.288 3144-3144/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe

                                        [ 05-16 11:51:17.288  3144: 3144 E/         ]
                                        ro.product_ship = true

                                        [ 05-16 11:51:17.288  3144: 3144 E/         ]
                                        ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c

                                        [ 05-16 11:51:17.288  3144: 3144 E/         ]
                                        sys.mobilecare.preload = false
05-16 11:51:17.288 5284-5284/? E/audit: type=1701 msg=audit(1494944477.288:292): auid=4294967295 uid=99011 gid=99011 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:isolated_app:s0:c512,c768 pid=6495 comm="Binder_4" exe="/system/bin/app_process64" sig=11
05-16 11:51:17.288 3480-3588/? I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_06 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
05-16 11:51:17.298 3480-3572/? W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /system/app/SPrintSpooler6/SPrintSpooler6.apk / 1.0 running in null rsrc of package com.android.printspooler
05-16 11:51:17.328 3167-3167/? I/Zygote: Process 6058 exited due to signal (11)
05-16 11:51:17.328 11898-12249/? E/PrintActivity: Error dropping pages
                                                  android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
                                                      at com.android.printspooler.renderer.IPdfEditor$Stub$Proxy.write(IPdfEditor.java:198)
                                                      at com.android.printspooler.ui.PrintActivity$DocumentTransformer.doTransform(PrintActivity.java:3052)
                                                      at com.android.printspooler.ui.PrintActivity$DocumentTransformer.access$5900(PrintActivity.java:2947)
                                                      at com.android.printspooler.ui.PrintActivity$DocumentTransformer$1.doInBackground(PrintActivity.java:2998)
                                                      at com.android.printspooler.ui.PrintActivity$DocumentTransformer$1.doInBackground(PrintActivity.java:2991)
                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest update of Android got rid of the problem.  I actually came across a bug fix reference but don't have a link to it at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

hard to tell why exactly this happens, it's not too smart to post just the crash without the code which caused it (`SIGSEV` means, that an invalid memory reference caused the crash)... therefore I can only provide an example, but cannot not tell what could have caused the invalid reference.

```
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
String jobName = this.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
printManager.print(jobName, pda, null);

PrintDocumentAdapter pda = new PrintDocumentAdapter(){

    @Override
    public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback){
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;

        try {

            input = new FileInputStream(file to print);
            output = new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor());

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                 output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES});

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ee){

        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            try {
                input.close();
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras){

        if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
            callback.onLayoutCancelled();
            return;
        }           

        PrintDocumentInfo pdi = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("Name of file").setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT).build();
        callback.onLayoutFinished(pdi, true);
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm using Google's pdf viewer to print the file so I have no access to the code. Sorry, I should've been clear on that in my post.  However, since both pdf viewer and Microsoft Word generate the same crash I must assume that the issue lies in Android's print spooler.  I was hoping that someone familiar with the spooler would give me some pointers.

Comment: @bdristan you should install the sources package for the Android SDK... which would enable you to break into this code:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/62ce332/packages/PrintSpooler/src/com/android/printspooler ...and set the breakpoints there, in order to rectify the concrete reason. or just set a breakpoint on the initial call and then proceed step-wise (which should take you to the `PdfManipulationService`)... but this only works while the sources package had been added.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: @bdristan while with "code" I've rather meant, the initial function call... because if I'd have to guess, I'd say that the parameters might refer to something out of bounds (in C `SIGSEV` is ordinary associated with pointers... so I wonder what it means in Java - unless it's thrown upwards into the framework - from the native assembly of Linux).